# React useReducer typeScripts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Hi every one i'm learning React hooks with typeScript and I have trubles with useReducer
I've understood the how does it work but I have errors when I'm implementing it in my project.

```html
const initalState: Istate = {
  counter: 1,
  name: "tt",
};
enum ActionKind {
  increase = "INCREASE",
  decrease = "DECREASE",
}
interface Action {
  type: ActionKind;
  payload: number;
}
interface Istate {
  counter: number;
  name: string;
}

function reducer(state: Istate, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREASE":
      return { count: state.counter + 1, name: state.name };
  }
}

export function Hooktest() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initalState);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={increment}>{counter}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I don't realy understand the eroor or what I've done wrong

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer should always return a state. Add a default to your `switch`. In addition, you have a typo in this line:

```
    return { count: state.counter + 1, name: state.name };
```

The key `count` should be `counter` according to your type.

This is how your reducer should look:

```
function reducer(state: Istate, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREASE":
      return { counter: state.counter + 1, name: state.name };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Your `Hooktest` component should use the `dispatch` with relevant action from `ActionKind` enum:

```
export function Hooktest() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: ActionKind.increase })}>
        {state.counter}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

And you should change the `Action` type's `payload` to optional, since you don't action need payload for the `INCREASE` action:

```
interface Action {
  type: ActionKind;
  payload?: number;
}
```

You can see a working example in this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/usereducer-with-ts-example-ihfdr2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).